# Suggestions on how to reduce accidentally deleting the wrong message in Outlook when receiving a new one?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

In Outlook 365, a user is receiving a high volume of new messages on a regular basis, on the scale of multiple per minute. As that user is monitoring and removing messages and they click the trash can icon on the right side of the inbox item, it is not uncommon for a new message to come in as they click it and the wrong message is deleted requiring extra steps to restore it.

Are there any good ways to prevent this? I looked into trying to segment messages into read and unread (something like a search folder or a rule) but have not had any luck since this is online rather than the desktop client. The user is competent but not savvy with this software so the simpler the solution from a usability standpoint the better.

Comment: right-click then delete instead.  the context menu will still refer to the appropriate email. or with the email highlighted use the delete key on the keyboard.  open the message and delete

Answer (score 1):

You can alleviate your problem by dividing emails into different inboxes by a certain partitioning standard.

For example, you can use the sender as the standard to send the mail sent by sender A to A inbox, and the mail sent by sender B to B inbox. These all can be finished by establishing mail flow rules in OWA.

Here are the specific steps:

1. In a web browser, sign in to Outlook Web App using the URL provided by the person who manages email for your organization. Enter your user name and password, and then select Sign in.
2. At the top of the page, select Settings > Options.
3. In Options, select Organize email > Inbox rules.

4.edit the rule name

5.Add a condition, you can choose Sender address includes, add the address.

6.Add an action, you can choose Move to the folder you want to move to.

7.Then click save.

For more information about deploy mail flow rule on OWA，you also can info this Microsoft Blog:[enter link description here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/inbox-rules-in-outlook-web-app-edea3d17-00c9-434b-b9b7-26ee8d9f5622)

Comment: I am writing here to check whether your problems have been solved? If it is ,please mark the helpful answer as the "accepted answer", If not ,please reply ,we will try our best to help you.